# Sorting test results on Tests tab in Azure DevOps pipeline

Tags: azure

I run frontend tests for a webapp using WebdriverIO/Selenium as a nightly build defined in the Pipelines section of Azure DevOps.

For each build I can view test results on the `Tests` tab, which will show me statistics on all tests and a list of tests that I can filter and group.

[image: Azure DevOps Tests tab statistics and filter options]

Until a few days ago, this list was automatically sorted alphabetically, now it is not sorted in any obvious way. I cannot find any option to sort the list, and the [Azure DevOps page on reviewing test results](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/review-continuous-test-results-after-build?view=vsts) does not mention sorting at all. I have also not had any luck using Google.

Is there a way to sort this list, e.g. by test name? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that at this point sorting test results in only possible in the Tests menu, under Test Runs.

[image]

See also this question's [duplicate on stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52734012/sorting-test-results-on-tests-tab-in-azure-devops-pipeline/).